# Distance to Circle Center JS

Tags: javascript, math, geometry

Ok I my math is quite bad...
Though, can anybody tell me some formula with which I get following?
Any resources would be great too

I have a circle where I know the radius. And I have a chord where I only know the length of it. I now need to know the distance between the center of the circle and the center of the chord.

Any help is great for me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it would be `Math.sqrt(r*r - d*d/4)` where `r` is the radius and `d` is the length of the chord.

you can see this if you draw the line from the circle centre to the chord midpoint.  from symmetry the line must join at a right angle, so you have a right angle triangle (hypotenuse length `r`, one side length `d/2`), and the above comes from [pythagoras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem).

Comment: fantastic, thanks a lot. have you any good resources for math-stuff? I always find either pages for kids or for einsteins...

Comment: no problem.  i'm afraid this was just from memory - i don't know where you'd find a good collection of this kind of thing.